# ovh/ovh requires guzzlehttp^6.0 while therobfonz/laravel-mandrill-driver requires guzzlehttp^7.0: is there any solution?

Tags: laravel, composer-php, mandrill, ovh

In my Laravel 8 project I had to install the mailer `therobfonz/laravel-mandrill-driver`; now I have to install the SMS driver `ovh/ovh`.

For the moment in my `composer.json` file I have:

```
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0",
    "therobfonz/laravel-mandrill-driver": "^3.0"
```

When I type: `composer require ovh/ovh`, I have this error:

> ovh/ovh v2.1.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.0).

I have tried to edit `composer.json` by changing the version of `guzzle` to "^6.0", then doing `composer update`. However this results in an error (`mandrill` requires `guzzle ^7.0`).

What could I do?

Comment: you need to downgrade any one of them to 6.x

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: use v2.0.4 for `therobfonz/laravel-mandrill-driver`, then it will be usable with guzzle 6.3

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this problem? If there is any package requiring Guzzle v7 and another requireing Guzzle v6, you need to check if up- or downgrading any of these helps to resolve the problem. For example, why not use `ovh/ovh` in v3 which is compatible with Guzzle v7?

Comment: Because in fact I must use https://github.com/ovh/php-ovh-sms which uses php-ovh (!v3) :)

Comment: So, what have you tried then? Why not submit a pull request to the "broken" package?

Comment: I'm going to fork the `php-ovh-sms` to support guzzle^7 yep :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVH v3.0.0 works with Guzzle 7.0

https://github.com/ovh/php-ovh/blob/75852ad0fee8008b6245d72a7d3ba7f09cb456ae/composer.json

Maybe you should just update OVH?